# split screen edit

Tags: video-sequence-editor

What is best practise when editing on a project with many clips in order to achieve a split screen effect?

I tend to render to file the first cut of the movie after applying transform to shift it to the left. Open a new blender project ad apply a mask to it and render to file. Same for the second cut. Re-import both on the main project and apply a translation to the second cut.

Surely there is a better way of doing this. I just don't know how.

========================

so for example using compositing (see picture below)..
I apply the mask (black bars) but how do I shift the movie to the left for example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer.
I have used the translate node

[image]